# Windows Azure Deployment only shows a SEMICOLON ( ; )

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, azure

I'm new in Windows Azure and in .NET. My task is to deploy an existing ASP.NET MVC3 (with local database connection) to windows azure. but after following all the instructions here

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/learn/tutorials/getting-started-tutorial/6-create-a-hosted-service/ ,

It only shows a semicolon on the page.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound good!

It's best to be very systematic when debugging something in Azure as there are lots of layers around your code. Start simple, then build up, until you find what doesn't work.

So, first, verify that your site works when run using the Visual Studio Development Server. You may need to put your database connection string into `web.config` to get this to work. If you see problems here, use "view source" to verify that the ASP.NET MVC side of things is working as it should: it may be something trivial like a missing close angle bracket `>`.

Then, check it works when you configure the site to run under IIS locally.

Next, make sure the site works properly in the Compute Emulator. If it works under IIS but not the Compute Emulator then the chances are there's something wrong in your configuration. (Come back here with specifics as this step usually doesn't fail unless you're doing something unusual at Web role startup.)

Then, check that the site has actually deployed properly to Azure. Use `ping` at the command prompt to verify that the DNS entries are all configured properly and your site is being called correctly. You may find that to narrow down the issue you need to stub out your call to the database.

Comment: Actually, the application is running perfectly using the local server and with my local database. Also i was able to run the application using the Azure SQL...  

About the Compute Emulator, it is also running (coz it is visible in my taskbar), but im not sure how to identify if its working or not. 

While i only receive a "Request Timeout" when pinging the application. 

I hope it can give more details about the problem. Thanks man!